# Scrollspy is making the wrong link active on page load

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

For some odd reason scrollspy is causing my second list item to be active on page load instead of the first one. It's weird because after I scroll a bit with the mouse it will make the correct list item active. Aside from this error it functions perfectly. If someone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

Heres my html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

  </head>
   <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="111">
  <header id="home">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top cbp-af-header">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        Determined Divas
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li  id="home" class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#whoWeAre">Who We Are</a></li>
        <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="content">
<!-- Home page row -->
  <div class="row" id="home">
    <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(img/LP/pathways_12.jpg)"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- About Section -->
  <section class="row" id="about">     
           <!-- Title -->
    <div class="row title-row"> 
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h1>About</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
          <!-- Content -->
    <div class="row content-row">

    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- Who We Are Section -->
  <section class="row" id="whoWeAre">     
           <!-- Title -->
    <div class="row title-row"> 
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h1>Who We Are</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
          <!-- Content -->
    <div class="row content-row">

    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- Gallery -->
  <section class="row" id="gallery">     
           <!-- Title -->
    <div class="row title-row"> 
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h1>Gallery</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
          <!-- Content -->
    <div class="row content-row">

    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- Contact-->
  <section class="row" id="contact">     
           <!-- Title -->
    <div class="row title-row"> 
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h1>Contact</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
          <!-- Content -->
    <div class="row content-row">

    </div>
  </section>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Scripts to animated the nav -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Animated Header/classie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Animated Header/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>
<!-- Smooth Scrolling -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<!-- Script for full screen bg image -->
<script src="js/fillscreen.js"></script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Heres the CSS:

```
    body{
        position: relative;
        background-color: #FFF2E2;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;

       /*Keeps page content under the header, must match navbar height*/
      /*padding-top: 75px; */

     }

    /*NAV STYLING*/
    .navbar-default{
        height: 76px;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        -webkit-animation: all 0.5s;

    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav{
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
      color: white;
      font-size: 2.0em;
      font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
      font-weight: bolder;
    }

     .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
        color: white;
    }

      .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
      color: #777;
    }

   .navbar-default {
       background-color: #E498AF;
   }

    /*Controls active nav items*/
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
      color: #777;

   }


        /*Animate nav on scroll*/
    .cbp-af-header-shrink{
       height: 51px;

     }

    /*Full screen image styles*/
    .fill{
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
     }

     /*Title Row Styling*/
    .title-row{
        height: 100px;
        color: #777;
        background-color: #FFF2E2;
        text-align: center;
     }

    /*Content row styling*/
    .content-row{
       height: 600px;
       background-color: white;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

that is because you have

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="111">
```

data target of navbar class but you html markup has

```
  <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
```

id navbar; switch either one and should work.

bootstrap scrollspy will look for a target then default to a nav if it cant find the target or if a target is not specified. Its also better to put the scrollspy on a div that only contains the navigation

here is a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/0ru2f07m/)

Comment: put your markup in a fiddle... or something like that